# Biztalk AS2 decryption component size limit

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I am getting following error when I am trying to receive file bigger than 100 MB. I was getting same error when I was trying file bigger than 5MB and I applied windows CU5. Now I can receive big file (I tested till 60 MB). New file which is coming is 110MB and we start getting this error.

Can somebody help me to figure out this issue.

I am using Biztalk 2010 with windows 2008 server.

> A message received by adapter "HTTP" on receive location "RecLocAS2All" with URI "/xxxxxx/BTSHTTPReceive.dll" is suspended. 
>    Error details: An output message of the component "Microsoft.BizTalk.EdiInt.PipelineComponents" in receive pipeline "Microsoft.BizTalk.EdiInt.DefaultPipelines.AS2Receive, Microsoft.BizTalk.Edi.EdiIntPipelines, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" is suspended due to the following error: 
>        An error occurred when decrypting an AS2 message..
>    The sequence number of the suspended message is 2.

Comment: Based on Microsoft document   AS2 Message Size Limitation
Encrypted AS2 messages should be smaller than 96 megabytes in order to be processed. This limitation is imposed by the AS2 Decoder, which is the part of the AS2Receive and AS2EdiReceive pipelines.
One way to work around this size limitation is to use compression, because an AS2 message is compressed before it is encrypted.

Answer (score 2):

As per your own comment the message size before encryption needs to be reduced by compressing it.

[Known Issues with AS2 Processing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb226414.aspx)

> **AS2 Message Size Limitation**
>
> Encrypted AS2 messages should be smaller than 96 megabytes in order to be processed. This limitation is imposed by the AS2 Decoder, which is the part of the AS2Receive and AS2EdiReceive pipelines.
> One way to work around this size limitation is to use compression, because an AS2 message is compressed before it is encrypted.

Although that article is the BizTalk 2013/R2 version it would probably be the same for earlier version of BizTalk (as that component hasn't significantly changed apart from the Trading Parties).

You would have to get whomever is sending you the EDI message to enable compression at their end.

An other option would be to get them to split any large batches into smaller messages rather than one big batch.

You might want to update to the [latest CU](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2855367) which currently is CU6 for BizTalk 2010. If you were to escalate this issue to Microsoft support, they won't even want to help you until you are on the latest CU.

Comment: Thanks,First thing I ask my customer to send compressed one, but he denied that. So looking out other option and keeping that as last option for now.